# Is reflection actually due to very low critical angle?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

When we take an example of a plane mirror, does the reflection occur because the critical angle for the silvered surface is very small? Are all the good reflectors good at reflecting because their small critical angle or is it some other phenomenon?

Comment: In general, when reflection occurs in air medium, air is optically less dense while the silvered surface is optically more dense.But the concept of critical angle is defined for light passing from optically denser to optically rarer medium. So your assumption of a relation between reflection and critical angle is promptly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There's no critical angle for light traveling from air (or another transparent medium) into a conducting medium;  even if you shine a light at a perfect 90° angle to such an interface, it will still be almost entirely reflected.

Rather, the reason for reflection is that if you try to set up electromagnetic waves in a conducting medium, the electric field of the wave drives currents around:  $\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E}$, which is the microscopic version of Ohm's Law.  As you might be aware, you can derive the wave equation from Maxwell's equations for transparent media;  if you try to do the same for conducting media, you find that the waves do *not* maintain their amplitude as they move through a conductor, but instead die off exponentially.  The characteristic length scale on which this happens (i.e., the distance for the wave amplitude to go down by $1/e$) is called the *skin depth*, because an incoming wave drops off to essentially zero below a thin "skin" near the surface of the conductor.  Skin depth is dependent on the frequency of the wave and the permeability and conductivity of the material;  all other things being equal, better conductors have smaller skin depths;  at visible frequencies, the skin depth for silver is on the order of nanometers.

On a qualitative level, you can then explain the reflection of waves by energy considerations.  The energy of the incoming wave can in principle end up in one of three places:  continuing to propagate through the conductor;  reflected;  or dissipated by Joule heating (since you have currents flowing in a conductor.)  But since the wave dies off very quickly, very little of it penetrates the conductor;  and since the currents only flow in a small region below the surface of the conductor, not very much of the energy gets dissipated as heat.  This means that almost all of the energy is reflected, which in turn means that the reflected wave has almost the same amplitude as the incoming wave.  Hence, reflection that is almost (but not quite) perfect.

You can actually apply a surprising amount of the formalism from transparent media to conducting media;  the catch is that a conductor has to be thought of as having a complex, frequency-dependent impedance and index of refraction, and the wave vector $\vec{k}$ is complex as well.  Once you've done that, though, the Fresnel equations still apply.